# json_encode limitation records

Tags: php, arrays, json

So, does anyone knew there's limitation php to encode array using `json_encode` ?

I fetch from SQLServer using below code and it was succesful until the last 2 lines of `json_encode`,

```
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,  SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))        
    {
       array_push($items, $row);        
    }

    $result = array();
    $result["data"] = $items;

    echo count($items);
    echo "<br/>";
    echo count($result);
    echo "<br/>";
    echo count($result["data"]);
    echo "<br/>";

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($result, 128);
```

I have search to the [phpmanual](http://php.net/manual/en/json.configuration.php), and although not mentioning anything about increased the memory, my settings at `php.ini` is set to 2GB, so I am sure that's not the case.

When I count the array before encode, they return the rows just fine.

Thus, I did little test, increase the memory at php.ini and use SELECT TOP in the query, found out that it can return 6670 data rows using SELECT TOP (6670) *,

but ...

not one record show after I changed it to 6671 or just SELECT * which supposedly return about 13522 data rows, while I need them all?

Comment: you can't change content-type after using echo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: "supposedly" - make sure

Comment: It looks like you want to return 2 different responses (HTML and JSON) to the same request which is not possible in HTTP protocol. The problem you are facing is indeed described in answers suggested by @Terminus, but it is unlikely to help you as you probably should be doing something different altogether (i.e. rendering inline JavaScript). Clarifying your actual goal may help someone to answer your question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov what's echoing out is just the counts of the array in different ways. It appears to be debugging code. If he wants that info on his page he simply needs to do a `.length` on the `JSON.parse ()`d responseText. The solution is removing the debug code.

Comment: Not that you're wrong about the impossibility of having 2 different responses in the same request, +1